# Stucked in the model migration in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a problem during migrating 3 models (Game,Page,Section), which is I created 3 models and forget to save it, then directly migrate it. After that, I created a new model called User, then save it, and this User model perfectly saved and migrated successfully. After that when checked schema, those 3 models did not have any fields and did not migrated.

So I did the rake db:rollback, it only rollback to User Model, but I want those 3 Models to be rollbacked. I cannot do new migration to put new values.

Q1 : So do I need to delete those 3 models and create new models?

Comment: I am not sure about your issue because creating models and not saving them and directly migrating statements are not clear. But you can check the migration status using: `rake db:migrate:status` which will give you some idea.

Answer (score 0):

If it is your personal project just to learn, you can drop your database and, modify migration files and then create and migrate it.

1. `rake db:drop`
2. modify migration files
3. `rake db:create`
4. `rake db:migrate`

But you will lose all you data in database, so it is very bad idea for future. Better learn how you can create another migrations and add columns  you need for your tables.
Look here: [add_column](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.2.7/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements/add_column)

Ot you can always rollback few migrations using `rake db:rollback STEP=n`